# AlarmManager not launch only one time a day

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to launch an activity (A1) at 5pm each day from an other activity (A2) and after 30 minutes i want to get back to the first activity(A2). 
My problem is that at 5pm the good activity (A1) is launched and after 30 min the first activity(A2) is launched to but immediately it get back to (A1) and it's looped for ever.

```
public class A1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = A1.class.getName();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private StringRequest mStringRequest;
private String url = "http://server/welcome/controller/getannonce.php";
protected TextView Annonce;
protected static int TIME_OUT = 1800000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_close);
    Annonce=findViewById(R.id.textAnnonce);
    //RequestQueue initialized
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //String Request initialized
    mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Annonce.setText(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.i(TAG,"Error :" + error.toString());
        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(A1.this, A2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, TIME_OUT);

}
```

}

```
public class A2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = A2.class.getName();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, launchClose.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarm.setWindow(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),15000, pendingIntent);
}
```

}

```
public class launchClose extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = launchClose.class.getName();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myintent = new Intent(context, A1.class);
    myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myintent);
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe not related but if your app uses internet then I would suggest using time from some online api instead of depending on mobile device time that a user can change. It would be bad user experience I think.

Comment: my app doesn't use internet.